# xpath for html table values

Tags: python, html, lxml

I have a HTML like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
   <tr>
       Text before Text1
       <td>Text1</td>
       Text after Text1
   </tr>
   <tr>
       Text before Text2
       <td>Text2</td>
       Text after Text2
   </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using lxml and Python. I want to use XPath to find `Text after Text1` and `Text after Text2`

I tried XPath `/html/body/table/tr` and get the text of relative path `./td`, but I can only get `Text before Text1` and `Text before Text2`.

So how can I achieve this?

One example:

```
<tr>
  <td width="16"><img alt="" src="http://source.qunar.com/site/images/airlines/small/HU.gif"></td>
  <td valign="top">海航<span class="dc">HU7605</span><br>首都T1-虹桥/td>
</tr>
```

I can find `海航` but can't find `首都T1-虹桥`.

Comment: what is after ? it is not a valid html markup if it is text

Comment: @vittore Yes AFTER1 is a text value.

Comment: @vittore I just edited the example. I want to get "Text after Text1" and "Text after Text2"

Answer (score 1):

Pretend you file is in `data.xml`.

```
from lxml import etree

data = etree.parse('data.xml')

for row in data.xpath('/html/body/table/tr'):
    before, after = row.xpath('text()')
    print before, after
```

Comment: oneAirline.xpath("text()")
['上航', '\r\n\t\t\t首都T2-虹桥\r\n    \t  \t']

Answer (score 0):

You can get Xpath Values like this

```
             "//tr"  or "//tr/td"
```

Comment: "//tr" get all the tr. But if the table is one table in a big html, it will very hard to find which one.

Comment: Then u have to Write a Query for this to find which node u want